# How to deploy helm chart to ecr via github actions?

Tags: github, kubernetes-helm, github-actions, amazon-ecr

Im trying to create a github action which will push to ECR , how do I push helm chart to ECR with Actions yaml?

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure [AWS Credentials](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials)
2. Configuration [AWS ECR Login](https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login) ** Please note that at the time of this writing this action does not support helm repository logins. You need to use a different branch, aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login**@arjraman**
3. use helm to package the chart using helm package
4. use helm to push the packaged chart to the ECR using helm push

Here's a custom action that utilizes the steps described above.

```
name: AWS Helm
description: AWS Setup and Helm Chart
inputs:
  aws-access-key-id:
    description: The AWS access Key id
    required: true
  aws-secret-access-key:
    description: The AWS access key
    required: true
  ecr-repository-name:
    description: the name of the ecr repository
    required: true
  aws-region:
      description: The AWS region, default us-east-2
      default: us-east-2
      required: false
  tag-name:
    description: image tag name
    required: true
  chart-path:
    description: the directory path to the specified chart
    required: true
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ inputs.aws-access-key-id }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ inputs.aws-secret-access-key }}
        aws-region: ${{ inputs.aws-region }}
    # This is  an un-official build that allows helm login to the ECR
    - uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@arjraman
      id: login-ecr
    - name: Helm Chart
      env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ inputs.ecr-repository-name }}
      run : |
        helm package \
        ${{ inputs.chart-path }} \
        --app-version ${{ inputs.tag-name }} \
        --version ${{ inputs.tag-name }}
        helm push "${{ inputs.ecr-repository-name }}-${{ inputs.tag-name }}.tgz" oci://$ECR_REGISTRY
      shell: bash
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Configure](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials) AWS credentials.
2. [Install](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/helm-tool-installer) helm.
3. Authenticate with ECR:

```
aws ecr get-login-password \
     --region <aws-region> | helm registry login \
     --username AWS \
     --password-stdin <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com
```

4. Push like you would for any other repository:

```
helm chart push <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/<ecr-repo>:mychart
```